# Wireguard siplified connect to server

Tags: wireguard

When using ovpn on my local machine I usually just write
`openvpn client.ovpn`

and I connect to my server just fine, but with wireguard there is just way too much stuff written.

I need to generate some ip table, keys, etc.

Can you give me bash script that will work like it was with openvpn? Like

```
bash wireguard.sh client.conf
```

this one will connect my machine to server and act as ordinary vpn